# How to make an slide animation while bringing an custom view in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm developing an app where when clicking to a button, custom view should slide from a side. Actually just a window appears, but I'd like to have something like iOS navigation controller. How this can be done? This is for an Mac OS X app.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a Core Animation transition. You need to turn on layer backing for the parent view, and then you can do

```
[[parentView animator] replaceSubview:oldView with:newView];
```

By default that will crossfade the views, but if you want to change it to a slide animation then you'd add the appropriate CATransition to the animations dictionary.

```
- (CATransition *)slideAnimation
{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    [transition setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
    [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    return transition;
}
```

and then to set that animation in your parentView

```
...
[parentView setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self slideAnimation] forKey:@"subviews"];
...
```

Comment: It works! but the animation doesn't works :( how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you call setAnimations: whenever the parentView was created? Sorry, looking now that could have been made clearer

Comment: If you are using the most recent version of the API/XCode, the last line can be reduced to `parentView.animations = @{@"subviews":self.slideAnimation}`

Comment: I added `parentView.wantsLayer = YES;parentView.animations = @{@"subviews":self.slideAnimation}` in `awakeFromNib`. problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `animator`. Here is a sample:

```
NSPoint startPoint = NSMakePoint(NSWidth([[self window] frame]), NSHeight([[self window] frame]) - NSHeight([view frame]));
[view setFrameOrigin:startPoint];
NSPoint endPoint = NSMakePoint(0.0f, startPoint.y);
[[view animator] setFrameOrigin:endPoint];
```

Comment: Can we set animation duration here.

Comment: @Imran Yes, add this line: [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:duration];

Answer (score 1):

iain's answer is great!
If it doesn't work, check if you call [prentView setWantsLayer:YES] somewhere in your code.

Comment: That's why he wrote "You need to turn on layer backing for the parent view" which you can also do in Interface Builder by checking the appropriate checkbox, you don't necessarily require code for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSView *view = yourview;
view.wantsLayer = YES;
```

// Set the layer redraw policy. This would be better done in the initialization method of a NSView subclass instead of here.

```
 view.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay;
```

Then,

```
 [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context)
                    {
                        context.duration = 2.f;
                        view.animator.frame = CGRectOffset(view.frame, 180, 0);
                    }
                    completionHandler:^{
                        view.hidden = YES;


                    }];
```