# Replacing a subview with Core Animation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation, core-animation

The animator proxy in **Core Animation** works pretty good, however the animation can be unclean if you try to animate the frame of a view. The frame rate is pretty bad, that's what I mean.
My view that I animate has a lot of subviews, this is why the animation get's even worse.

I found this tutorial on how to do this with **Core Animation**:
http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/03/core-animation-tutorial-wizard-dialog-with-transitions/

However, if you run the example code you'll see that the animation has an opacity animation too, and it looks very odd. So I'd like to make a custom animation.

It would be great if someone could provide me the solution of this problem.
Or give me some proper resources where I can do some research.

I need a `ease-in-out` animation from the `bottom to top` and `top to bottom`.
Like the mail-tableview in **Sparrow**.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you're asking for here. Are you wanting something like this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916429/how-to-make-an-slide-animation-while-bringing-an-custom-view-in-cocoa

Comment: @iain The link you provided replaces the view just like in the link I provided. I'm just looking for a efficient way to replace a view with a custom animation. `kCATransitionMoveIn` has a strange alpha animation, which I don't like.

Comment: You can just put any CIFilter transition in the filter property of CATransition. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html There's not going to be a way to do it faster than using Coreanimation.

Comment: Would `kCATransitionPush` be what you're looking for?

Comment: I think that basically does the same thing, but I will try and come back to you

Comment: @iain I know that Core Animation is the fastest way, but not the animator proxy. That was the only working solution I had on this topic.

Comment: Like I said, your question made it very hard to make out what you were wanting.

Comment: @iain Sorry, I tested `kCATransitionMoveIn` and the alpha value is still animated too.